# Building 2 large SharePoint lists which have many to many relationships between them

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, powerapp, architecture

We have 2 SharePoint lists:-

1. Assets
2. Spare Parts

Now a Spare Part can be linked to more than one Asset and an Asset can have more than one Spare Part. Now the straightforward way to implement this inside SharePoint is to create a lookup field which allow multiple selection either inside the Assets list or inside the Spare Parts list. but this approach has the following Disadvantages :-

1. The Lookup column which allow multiple selection cannot be indexed inside SharePoint
2. Filter the Assets based on the spare part or Filter the spare parts based on the Asset will not be delegable inside power app.

so what is the correct approach to overcome the above 2 limitation?

For example i am thinking instead of creating a lookup field, to create a third list which represents the many to many relation, and store the AssetID and the SparePartID inside it. in this case we can overcome the above 2 limitations.

any advice/comments? on my issue and the approach I am proposing?

Thanks